# Quotient Rings and Homomorphic Images in $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

(This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 19, Exercise C4.)

Let $\phi$ be the function from 
$\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R})$ defined as follows: 
\begin{align*}
    \phi(f) &= f_{\mathbb{Q}} = \text{the restriction of }f\text{ to }\mathbb{Q}
\end{align*}
(Note the domain of $f_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ and on this domain $f_{\mathbb{Q}}$
is the same function as $f$.)

Let $J$ be the subset of $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all $f$ such that
$f(x)=0$ for every rational $x$.

> Explain why $J$ is an ideal of 
>   $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})/J\cong\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{Q})$.

Question: Is there a typo in the question in that the isomorphism should be $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})/J\cong\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R})$ rather than $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})/J\cong\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{Q})$ ?

The reason is that $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})/J\cong\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R})$, but $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R})$ is not isomorphic to $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{Q})$.
Let $\psi$ be the function from $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R})$ to 
$\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $\psi(f)$ is the restriction of the range of $f$ 
to $\mathbb{Q}$.  But $\psi$ is not well defined. For example, $\psi(f)$ would be undefined for the function $f(x) = \pi$ for
all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Am I right?

Comment: What is $\mathscr{F}(X,Y)$?  Is it supposed to be the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$? With $\mathscr{F}(X)$ being a shorthand for $X=Y$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathscr{F}(X,Y)$ is the set of all functions from domain X to range Y.  As far as I understand, $\mathscr{F}(X)$ is a short hand for $\mathscr{F}(X,X)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a typo, and should be $\mathscr F(\Bbb R)/J\cong \mathscr F(\Bbb Q, \Bbb R)$.